# No issuer certificate for certificate in certification path found

Tags: java

I am trying to build an app for [Token Browser](http://developers.tokenbrowser.com/docs/configuration), I have followed all the instructions. Created a Docker Environment and entered all the configuration. When I'm running the `docker-compose up` I receive the following error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
org.whispersystems.signalservice.api.push.exceptions.PushNetworkException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: No issuer certificate for certificate in certification path found.
```

Notes: Received this on both Linux 16.04 (Virtual Box) and Windows 10 Home.